# How does TXAA work?

Tags: anti-aliasing

From what I can gather, TXAA is an nvidia-developed, nvidia-specific anti-aliasing technique. Also it's temporal anti-aliasing which, as I understand, means it reduces aliasing in moving scenes (correct me if I'm wrong). I also read that it has a blur effect that is more noticeable than most other common techniques (someone was saying on a forum that it is very bad and incredibly noticeable). I have seen the demos on [this page of the nvidia website](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/txaa/technology) but they do not show still scenes for comparison. **Nvidia doesn't even explain what the abbreviation stands for** and I am yet to find a website that does.

The page I linked does say this:

> To filter any given pixel on the screen, TXAA uses a contribution of samples, both inside and outside of the pixel, in conjunction with samples from prior frames, to offer the highest quality filtering possible.

but it doesn't say what it does with those samples.

Both layman's and technical explanations are very welcome.

Comment: Start here-> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_anti-aliasing

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Okay so this explains temporal AA and I understand it now, but still no idea what the specifics of TXAA are.

Comment: Sorry, I don't either, I was just trying to point out some more info for you.